# ValueError - didn't return an HttpResponse object. - In Delete View Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am getting `ValueError` while deleting a user

Error -

> ValueError at /employee/delete/31/
>
> The view apps.employee.views.EmployeeDeleteView didn't return an HttpResponse
>   object. It returned None instead.

```
class EmployeeDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.DeleteView):
    model = User
    template_name = 'employee/employee_confirm_delete.html'
    context_object_name='employees'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Tab Opts Checking
        if request.user.userprofile.user_company.company_tab_opts:
            return redirect('admin_employee')

    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        self.object.userprofile.soft_delete()
        messages.success(request, 'Employee Deleted Successfully.')
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('admin_employee'))
```

This is the traceback of the error

```
Internal Server Error: /employee/delete/31/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/.virtualenvs/apollo_django-njoxc1BQ/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/.virtualenvs/apollo_django-njoxc1BQ/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 137, in _get_response
    "returned None instead." % (callback.__module__, view_name)
ValueError: The view apps.employee.views.EmployeeDeleteView didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
```

Comment: Seems like in your `get` method you return `redirect` after `if` condition. But if your `if` return `False` your `get` method returns `None`.

Comment: you need to return something if your IF condition in get method is false

Comment: Oh i got your point. I have removed the `get` method and put the `if` condition in `delete` method. Then it wroking. Thank you for your comment. But i don't know is it right approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here what i did. But don't know is it right approach

```
class EmployeeDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.DeleteView):
    model = User
    template_name = 'employee/employee_confirm_delete.html'
    context_object_name='employees'


    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Tab Opts Checking
        if request.user.userprofile.user_company.company_tab_opts:
            return redirect('admin_employee')
        self.object = self.get_object()
        self.object.userprofile.soft_delete()
        messages.success(request, 'Employee Deleted Successfully.')
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('admin_employee'))
```

Comment: it depends on your requirements. `get` is used for showing the form the first time (usually to show the object to delete and ask the user to confirm), `delete` is called when the user submits the form (usually after clicking a confirmation button, like 'yes, i'm sure'). So here, the user says 'yes I'm sure' but in a certain condition, you don't actually delete but redirect the user to another page. If that's what the business requirements are then your code is fine.